# devise, what is /my_users/password/edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've done a very basic devise setup (devise 3.3.0, rails 4.1.5, ruby 2.1.1). 
I let it create the model (`rails g devise:install` and `rails devise my_user`) in my emtpy application.
Let's have a look at the routes that now i have (i've added blank lines for better viewing):

```
 1         new_my_user_session    GET    /my_users/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#new
 2             my_user_session    POST   /my_users/sign_in(.:format)         devise/sessions#create
 3     destroy_my_user_session    DELETE /my_users/sign_out(.:format)        devise/sessions#destroy

 4            my_user_password    POST   /my_users/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#create
 5        new_my_user_password    GET    /my_users/password/new(.:format)    devise/passwords#new
 6       edit_my_user_password    GET    /my_users/password/edit(.:format)   devise/passwords#edit
 7                                PATCH  /my_users/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update
 8                                PUT    /my_users/password(.:format)        devise/passwords#update

 9 cancel_my_user_registration    GET    /my_users/cancel(.:format)          devise/registrations#cancel

10        my_user_registration    POST   /my_users(.:format)                 devise/registrations#create

11    new_my_user_registration    GET    /my_users/sign_up(.:format)         devise/registrations#new
12   edit_my_user_registration    GET    /my_users/edit(.:format)            devise/registrations#edit
13                                PATCH  /my_users(.:format)                 devise/registrations#update
14                                PUT    /my_users(.:format)                 devise/registrations#update
15                                DELETE /my_users(.:format)                 devise/registrations#destroy
```

Now let's recap:

```
[1,2]       user sign in (available w/o authentication)
[3]         user sign out
[4,5]       forgotten password form (w/o authentication)
[6,7,8]     editing password? WHAT DOES IT DO THIS?
[9]         cancel registration?
[10,11]     user sign up (registration of a new user) 
[12,13,14]  user editing his data
[15]        user delete himself
```

I'm expecially interested in understand what are meant to do the 6,7,8 actions, that seem to edit the password, but actually don't. Infact, there are two other ways of doing this, that are:

1. 'forgotten password' capability (actions 4,5)
2. 'edit user' capability (actions 12,13,14)

The second question is, what does it do the cancel registration action?

### Edit 1

Moreover, the my_user/password/edit route, whatever it is supposed to do, seems to be not working. When i browse it, i simply get redirected to the root page. 
Here is the log:

```
Started GET "/my_users/password/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-09-22 16:37:04 +0200
Processing by Devise::PasswordsController#edit as HTML
  MyUser Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "my_users".* FROM "my_users"  WHERE "my_users"."id" = 5  ORDER BY "my_users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Filter chain halted as :require_no_authentication rendered or redirected
```

Comment: Didn't you ever change a password? You know, the form with three field (current password, new password, new password confirmation). I bet that 6,7,8 are for this one.

Comment: perhaps i didn't explain very well. there is no one, but there are TWO other ways to change password, you know that form with three fields... (actions 12,13,14) :-) and the other one, that that allows you to do it via email

Answer (score 2):

`'forgotten password' capability (actions 4,5)`

This will generate new reset password token for registered email. This is a part of forgot password functionality.

`'edit user' capability (actions 12,13,14)`

This is also part of forgot password functionality. This will find user to edit on the basis of there reset password token and update password afterwards.

`The second question is, what does it do the cancel registration action?`

this will remove all session data user inserted during registration. Like clear functionality. below comment in devise registration cancel action. link here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

```
# GET /resource/cancel
# Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
# in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
# cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
# removing all OAuth session data.
```

Comment: fair enough for me, i thought that it was something like so... the problem is that in this very essential application... it doesn't work. The "change password form" (without logging out and without editing the whole profile) never comes out when you browse the root /my_users/password/edit. And you are simply redirected to the root. I know that this potentially is an entirely new and different question, but it is related because if it worked i would have easily guessed what it does.

Comment: Yes if all your other parts like forgot password working properly then it should also work. For this you should see your logs why it redirect you to root_url. Log will give you more insight for this. Why it redirecting.

Comment: forgot password works in the sense that shows the form (i didn't tested the email since i'm in development) but this doesn't :-( Let me have a look at logs

Comment: ok, i've edited the question, adding the development.log that i see on the server.

Comment: I have edited my answer after reading this link https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/plataformatec-devise/fEvXt9-80a4 . I was not right at first time. Have a look at this hope this will 100% clear your thoughts. And sorry for my wrong previous answer.